# The longest common subsequence for n string in java without using libraries?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to find a simple solution and I have read all the information or question that try to answer or have  solve the problem , and i have being testing.
I have found a solution which i converted from c#, and it works, but is too complicated and i do not understand how it works, so i was trying to make my own solution.

```
public static String lcs(String[] strings) {
    if (strings.length == 0)
        return "0";
    if (strings.length == 1)
        return strings[0];
    int max = -1;//max length of a string
    int cacheSize = 1; //multiplied length size of array with each other.
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        cacheSize *= strings[i].length();
        if (strings[i].length() > max)
            max = strings[i].length();
    }
    String[] cache = new String[cacheSize];
    int[] indexes = new int[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++)
        indexes[i] = strings[i].length() - 1;
    return lcsBack(strings, indexes, cache);
}

public static String lcsBack(String[] strings, int[] indexes, String[] cache) {
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++)
        if (indexes[i] == -1)
            return "";
    boolean match = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        if (strings[0].charAt(indexes[0]) != strings[i].charAt(indexes[i])) {
            match = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (match) {
        int[] newIndexes = new int[indexes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++)
            newIndexes[i] = indexes[i] - 1;
        String result = lcsBack(strings, newIndexes, cache) + strings[0].charAt(indexes[0]);
        cache[calcCachePos(indexes, strings)] = result;
        return result;
    } else {
        String[] subStrings = new String[strings.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            if (indexes[i] <= 0)
                subStrings[i] = "";
            else {
                int[] newIndexes = new int[indexes.length];
                for (int j = 0; j < indexes.length; j++)
                    newIndexes[j] = indexes[j];
                newIndexes[i]--;
                int cachePos = calcCachePos(newIndexes, strings);
                if (cache[cachePos] == null)
                    subStrings[i] = lcsBack(strings, newIndexes, cache);
                else
                    subStrings[i] = cache[cachePos];
            }
        }
        String longestString = "";
        int longestlength = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < subStrings.length; i++) {
            if (subStrings[i].length() > longestlength) {
                longestString = subStrings[i];
                longestlength = longestString.length();
            }
        }
        cache[calcCachePos(indexes, strings)] = longestString;
        return longestString;
    }
}

static int calcCachePos(int[] indexes, String[] strings) {
    int factor = 1;
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        pos += indexes[i] * factor;
        factor *= strings[i].length();
    }
    return pos;
}
```

So on what i understand i have being able, to make this method which is simple, but still doesn't work.
And i know from readings that the best way to solve this is using dinamic programming I would appreciate if somebody can help, thank you

```
    /**
     * @param strArr .
     * @return String
     */
    public String findCommonString(String[] words) throws Exception {
        try {
            String commonStr = "";
            String tempCom = "";
            char[] longestWordChars = findTheLongestString(words).toCharArray();
            for (char c : longestWordChars) {
                tempCom += c;

                for (String word : words) {
                    if (!word.contains(tempCom)) {
                        tempCom = Character.toString(c);
                        for (String word2 : words) {
                            if (!word2.contains(tempCom)) {
                                tempCom = "";
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (tempCom != "" && tempCom.length()>commonStr.length()) {
                    commonStr = tempCom;
                    //strArr = removeFirstOccurrence(strArr, tempCom);
//                  tempCom = "";

                }
            }
            return commonStr;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("[findCommonString] [STATUS] - ERROR ");
            logger.warn("[findCommonString] [EXCEPTION] " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }

    /**
     * @param strArr .
     * @return String
     */
    public String findTheLongestString(String[] words) throws Exception { // test
        try {
            String longestWord = "";

            for (String s : words) {
                if (longestWord.length() < s.length()) {
                    longestWord = s;
                }
            }
            return longestWord;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("[findTheLongestString] [STATUS] - ERROR ");
            logger.warn("[findTheLongestString] [EXCEPTION] " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I have being testing with this two test unit example

```
@Test
public void SubsequenceServiceTest3() throws Exception {
    assertEquals("CDAC", subsequenceService.findCommonSequence(new String[] { "BCDAACD", "ACDBAC" }));
}

@Test
public void SubsequenceServiceTest14() throws Exception {
    assertEquals("CA", subsequenceService.findCommonSequence(new String[] { "ACADB", "CBDA" }));
}
```

Comment: You may want to post your actual `findCommonSequence` code - it's not too clear how your `findCommonString` and `findTheLongestString` relate to it. Also, your second unit test will always fail since the longest subsequence between "ACADB" and "CBDA" is a tie between "CB", "CD", and "CA".

Comment: you have both method that i am using have a better look please, i have already included them and between "ACADB" and "CBDA" the CA is the result, sorry it was a typo i will fix it now.

Comment: for a better idea i have been focusing here https://www.programiz.com/dsa/longest-common-subsequence

Comment: Are your tests correct ? The comment subsequence between "ACADB" and "CA" shouldn't be "CA" ?

Comment: between "ACADB" and "CBDA" the CA is the result,

Comment: if you are testing you can use the code that i translated from c# into java , which is a solution, and i am trying to only to create a solution which i understand how it works